# Improve jQuery code optimization

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I've made some code which tests some conditions with if/else and adds/remove `active-class` according to which element is selected and I want to know if this code can be significantly reduced:

```
if filter.status == 'all'
  @$('.open, .closed, .ended, .resolved').removeClass('active-tab')
  @$('.all').addClass('active-tab')
else if filter.status == 'open'
  @$('.all, .closed, .ended, .resolved').removeClass('active-tab')
  @$('.open').addClass('active-tab')
else if filter.status == 'closed'
  @$('.all, .open, .ended, .resolved').removeClass('active-tab')
  @$('.closed').addClass('active-tab')
else if filter.status == 'ended'
  @$('.all, .open, .closed, .resolved').removeClass('active-tab')
  @$('.ended').addClass('active-tab')
else if filter.status == 'resolved'
  @$('.all, .open, .closed, .ended').removeClass('active-tab')
  @$('.resolved').addClass('active-tab')
```

Found the solution:

```
@$('.btn-filter.active').not(".btn-filter.#{filter.status}").removeClass('active')
@$(".btn-filter.#{filter.status}").addClass('active')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce it

```
var selector = '.all, .open, .closed, .ended, .resolved';
@$(selector).not('.'+filter.status).removeClass('active-tab')
@$('.'+filter.status).addClass('active-tab')
```